# Terminate tail command after timeout

Tags: bash, shell

I'm capturing *stdout* (log) in a file using `tail -f file_name` to save a specific string with `grep` and `sed` (to exit the tail) :

```
tail -f log.txt | sed /'INFO'/q |  grep 'INFO' > info_file.txt
```

This works fine, but I want to terminate the command in case it does not find the pattern (`INFO`) in the log file after some time

I want something like this (which does not work) to exit the script after a timeout (60sec):

```
tail -f log.txt | sed /'INFO'/q |  grep 'INFO' | read -t 60
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note [BashFAQ #68](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068).

Comment: ...btw, I'd consider using `awk` in place of the `grep`/`sed` logic here, given as it can do the work of both.

Comment: Actually, [BashFAQ #9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) is perhaps even more pertinent.

Comment: There's no need for `sed ... |`, the `grep` alone will do.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want to capture one line:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -r -t 60 line < <(tail -f log.txt | awk '/INFO/ { print; exit; }')
printf '%s\n' "$line" >info_file.txt
```

---

For a more general case, where you want to capture more than one line, the following uses no external commands other than `tail`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
end_time=$(( SECONDS + 60 ))
while (( SECONDS < end_time )); do
  IFS= read -t 1 -r line && [[ $line = *INFO* ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(tail -f log.txt)
```

---

A few notes:

- `SECONDS` is a built-in variable in bash which, when read, will retrieve the time in seconds since the shell was started. (It loses this behavior after being the target of any assignment -- avoiding such mishaps is part of why [POSIX variable-naming conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) reserving names with lowercase characters for application use are valuable).
- `(( ))` creates an arithmetic context; all content within is treated as integer math.
- `<( )` is a *process substitution*; it evaluates to the name of a file-like object (named pipe, `/dev/fd` reference, or similar) which, when read from, will contain output from the command contained therein. See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for a discussion of why this is more suitable than piping to `read`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me...

```
read -t 60 < <(tail -f log.txt | sed /'INFO'/q | grep 'INFO')
```

Comment: *nod*. Piping into `read` was the OP's most direct problem (though I don't know why they're bothering with the overhead of running both `sed` and `grep`; one could have `sed` do all the work, or -- my preference -- just delegate to `awk`).

Comment: BTW, is there value to `--color=auto` here? If there's a function or alias setting `--color=always`, that shouldn't be active inside a script, and (of course) it restricts portability to GNU `grep`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I expected I would need to worry about buffering, but it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Right, because buffers are flushed on exit. You'd need to worry about buffering if you were capturing more than one `INFO` line, but exiting after the first one gets you the flush "for free".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No idea where the `--color=always` came from, surely a copy/paste issue from my terminal window, I did not add that by hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is caused by the `/q` in the `sed` command, right?

Comment: Anyhow, good answer. I'm setting `IFS=` in mine to preserve leading and trailing whitespace, and passing `-r` to preserve backslash literals, but you've got the basics covered correctly.

Comment: Yup, the `q` is causing the exit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Ok, it makes sense now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) command, (part of the *Debian/Ubuntu* "coreutils" package), seems suitable:

```
timeout 1m tail -f log.txt | grep 'INFO'
```